# LitRPG book about a girl who lives in a tower in a post apocalyptic world

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a book I read. It's based on a girl who lives in a post-apocalyptic world in a tower. Two boys went out scrounging for things in the wasteland and found an apple core (for the seeds) which was taken by someone in the upper echelon. The person who took it was found dead and the boys were accused of doing it. The girl tries to help and ends up falling down a tube and somehow ends up in the game world and she tries to help the boys from there.

Comment: Welcome from the Facebook group. If I can get you to go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info, we have some prompts you can look through to try to elicit more details. Was this a Kindle book? I know most of the LitRPG books are.

Comment: Yea, it was a kindle book.  Pretty sure it was on Kindle Unlimited